# How to rearrange a string so no adjent letters are the same

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to rearrange a given string, so no two adjacent letters are the same.

For that I'm thinking to count every distinct letter's occurence, and then rearrange the string the characters occurence number

> example:
>
> Input: AABAABBC
>
> Output: AAAABBBC

and after that spliting it in 2 different strings

> AAAA BBBC

and then trying to get the final result.

My question is how do I rearrange the string without using Linq?

Here is my code so far:

```
private static string GetDistinctChars(string text)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (!result.Contains(c))
        {
            result += c;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static double GetCharOccurrence(string text, char charToCount)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (c == charToCount)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Does the original order matter? i.e. Can `AAAABBBC` be rearranged into `C AAAA BBB`? Also shouldn't it be 3 strings `AAAA`, `BBB`, `C`?

Comment: I think it matters because for the final step I will create the final string adding one character from the each strings like from AAAA BBBC -> ABABABAC
I hope you understand me, because I don't really know how to express myself

Comment: ah I misread your question so please don't mind what I said above. What if no possible legal arrangement can be found? For instance, what should you return when user inputs `AAAAB`?

Comment: I should return the character that can't be placed by the right rule, in this example is A

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-characters-string-no-two-adjacent/

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/reorganize-string/

Comment: Please add more examples to your question. I have a hard time following your explanations.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I have to reorganize a given string so that no adjacent letters are the same without using Linq. If this is not possible, the program shall return the letter that can't be reorganized by the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your problem on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorganize-string/), it's a **problem #767**.

My **algorithm** is

1. If we have *too many* of same characters, we can't solve the problem (e.g. `"aaaaaabc"`)
2. If solution exists, we can sort characters `aababc -> aaabbc` and then take item by item from the beginning and from the center:

**For instance:**

```
aababc -> aaabbc (ordered by frequency: a appears 3 time, b - 2, c - 1)

then

aaabbc      => ab
^  ^
take these  

aaabbc      => abab
 ^  ^
take these 

aaabbc      => ababac <- final answer
  ^  ^
take these
```

**Code:**

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    ...

    public static string ReorganizeString(string s) {
        int count = s.GroupBy(c => c).Max(g => g.Count());
        
        // One of the item is too frequent, no solutions 
        if (count > (s.Length + 1) / 2)
            return "";
        
        string st = string.Concat(s
            .GroupBy(c => c)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .ThenBy(g => g.Key) // not required, just for aesthetic
            .SelectMany(c => c));
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length / 2; ++i) {
            sb.Append(st[i]);
            sb.Append(st[(st.Length + 1) / 2 + i]);
        }
        
        // Middle character 
        if (s.Length % 2 != 0)
            sb.Append(st[st.Length / 2]);
        
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**Demo:**

```
string value = "AABAABBC";

Console.Write(ReorganizeString(value));
```

**Output:**

```
ABABABAC
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gWHpGL) it yourself.

**Edit:** If `StringBuilder` (as well as `System.Text`) is really *forbidden*, we can use `string`, which, however, *slows down* the routine:

```
    using System.Linq;
    ...

    public static string ReorganizeString(string s) {
        int count = s.GroupBy(c => c).Max(g => g.Count());
        
        // One of the item is too frequent, no solutions 
        if (count > (s.Length + 1) / 2)
            return "";
        
        string st = string.Concat(s
            .GroupBy(c => c)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .ThenBy(g => g.Key) // not required, just for aesthetic
            .SelectMany(c => c));
        
        string result = "";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length / 2; ++i) {
            result += st[i];
            result += st[(st.Length + 1) / 2 + i];
        }
        
        // Middle character 
        if (s.Length % 2 != 0)
            result += st[st.Length / 2];
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What does that StringBuilder sb do because it says that can't be found?

Comment: @Skike: you should mention `System.Text`; `StringBuilder` is class which helps to build a new string (usually in a loop);

Comment: I can't make it work, I will try to find another method

Comment: @Skike: I have added the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gWHpGL please, run the code with tests provided

Comment: Sorry, I mean the program works well, but the online course won't let me send it, I thik because they don't allow me to use System.Text yet.

Comment: @Skike: can't you declare it as `System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(s.Length);`? If you can't add `using` you can add namespace explicitly

Comment: I am still at a basics lesson, and I have to sove it with basic things and it's kinda annoying.

Comment: @Skike: well, you can shift from `StringBuilder` to `string` but this slows down the routine

Comment: Can I make this without Linq somehow? and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
string example = "AABBAACDCAA";

var orderList = example.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

List<string> letters = new List<string>();
string temp = string.Empty;
for(int i = 0; i < orderList.Count; i++)
{
    temp += orderList[i];
    if (i + 1 == orderList.Count)
    {
        letters.Add(temp);
        break;
    }

    if(orderList[i] != orderList[i + 1])
    {
        letters.Add(temp);
        temp = string.Empty;
    }
}

string result = String.Join(" ", letters);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you don't want to use Linq Order by method, you should implement sorting algorithm like this:

```
static char[] SortArray(char[] array)
{
    int length = array.Length;

    char temp = array[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp = array[i];

                array[i] = array[j];

                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

and use it in your program:

```
string example = "AABBAACDCAA";

var orderList = SortArray(example.ToCharArray());

List<string> letters = new List<string>();
string temp = string.Empty;
for(int i = 0; i < orderList.Length; i++)
{
    temp += orderList[i];
    if (i + 1 == orderList.Length)
    {
        letters.Add(temp);
        break;
    }

    if(orderList[i] != orderList[i + 1])
    {
        letters.Add(temp);
        temp = string.Empty;
    }
}

string result = String.Join(" ", letters);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

alternativly, if you don't want to use list anymore, you can operate only on strigns:

```
string example = "AABBAACDCAA";

var orderList = SortArray(example.ToCharArray());

string lettersString = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < orderList.Length; i++)
{
    lettersString += orderList[i];
    if (i + 1 == orderList.Length)
        break;

    if (orderList[i] != orderList[i + 1])
        lettersString += " ";
}

Console.WriteLine(lettersString);
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use list

Comment: Are you allowed to use only the String object methods? In your example you are using foreach with literally means that you are using list. So generally if it is algorithm question you should probably implement some of the sorting algorithm in c#, is that right?

Comment: Or maybe you are not allowed to use just a linq method? Anyway, you should treat your string like a char array at least if you want to rearrange it.

Comment: I think the linq method

Comment: I've added SortArray method which replace linq orderby.